# How to build this pacman project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, sfml

Hi, I want to build a PacMan game project which is on github (https://github.com/edoren/Pacman)

As i understood it needs three library naming STP, janssoon and SFML2.1 .

Can any one help me to set the required settings in in order to build and run it?

I am using win 8.1 and eclipse neon (c/C++)

please give me a step by step guide to install and setup every thing that is required (including the gcc 4.7 , SFML, STP, jansson , eclipse setting and so on.)

Comment: why do you give me negative point. i am new to this field so what is ordinary for you is new for me.

Comment: Are you the owner of the Pacman project, or are you trying to download their code and get it working?

Comment: SFML setup instructions are here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/, STP setup instructions are here: http://stp.github.io/, Jansson instructions hare here - https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.7/, Eclipse instructions are here - https://eclipse.org/users/, and gcc instructions are here - https://gcc.gnu.org/install/. Please add a more targeted question when you run across issues getting one of these set up for your machine, or when you have a problem using one of these with this project. As is, this question is much too broad to be answerable in a way that works well on stack overflow.

Comment: Also, I recommend using CMake, as the project author said in their readme. They didn't say on their page anything about using Eclipse. Every piece of software is different, and sometimes it is best not to use an IDE. Generic cmake build instructions are here - https://cmake.org/runningcmake/

Answer (score 2):

Why you do not use [CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/) like the owner of this project said?
This project was build on CMake. I think you couldn't use eclipse to do that...

Comment: I haven't used CMake yet. how can i use it for building and running this project ??

Comment: First, you can download CMake Here [link](https://cmake.org/download/).
After this, you can see these examples to run CMake: [link](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/)
And to use on Linux[link](https://tuannguyen68.gitbooks.io/learning-cmake-a-beginner-s-guide/content/chap1/chap1.html) and on windows [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878225/using-cmake-on-windows-for-c)

Comment: it is a little complicated for me. I don't understand what is going on. could you please give me a step by step guide EXACTLY for this SPECIFIC PACMAN PROJECT. thanks